# Image is showing extremely slow when selecting from ImagePicker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have not been able to figure out what might be the problem on why after selecting an image it takes 1-3 seconds just to show the picture. The array of images will have no more than 4 images.

I use useState with an array in order to hold all the photos

```js
// PHOTOS
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
```

When the component loads. I use `useEffect` in order to check that we do have selecting images granted as shown below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
      const { status } =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Next, we have a button that will run the `pickImage` function. This is responsible for getting the image that was selected, see if it is primary then add it to the array of photos.

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
  // Get the image from the phone
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
    exif: true,
  });

  // Set the photo as primary as true or false
  const photo = {
    isPrimary: photos.length === 0 ? true : false,
    url: result.uri,
  };

  // Update current primary
  if (photo.isPrimary) {
    setCurrentPrimary(photos.length);
  }

  // Add photo to the array
  setPhotos([...photos, photo]);
};
```

Lastly, we want to make sure we can see these images that are being added. We use a `FlatList`. This is done as:

```js
<FlatList
  data={photos}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.url}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View
        key={index}
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            alignContent: "center",
            alignSelf: "center",
            color: "white",
          }}
        >
          {index + 1}
        </Text>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.url }}
          style={{
            height: heightPercentageToDP(20),
            width: widthPercentageToDP(40),
            resizeMode: "contain",
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginRight: 20,
            justifyContent: "space-around",
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              color: item.isPrimary ? "red" : "blue",
            }}
          >
            <Button
              containerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: item.isPrimary ? "red" : "",
              }}
              color={item.isPrimary ? "green" : ""}
              title="Primary"
              onPress={() => makePrimary(index)}
            />
          </View>
          <Button
            color="red"
            title="Remove"
            onPress={() => removeImage(index)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>;
```

Any advice on which part might be causing the long lag is really appreciated. Also why this has happened. From my understanding, an array of just 4 images shouldn't cause a long lag and should be nearly instant especially when adding to an array.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried with smaller images size wise? also there is one package called Fast Image [Check that Out](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image#ac) . if you want to add this package as component I am using it you can ask me. I will mail you the file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I was compressing the quality of images (and compressing needs processing time). I was passing prop **compressImageQuality: 0.8** and then I removed it and it started working fine.

My code:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
...
const images = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
    maxFiles: 50,
    minFiles: 1,
    mediaType: 'photo',
    compressImageQuality: 0.8, // remove this prop for multiple images
  });
```

Opinion: Pass following props if you really need them, because they need processing time and I think you should not give these options to user when he is selecting multiple images.

```
allowsEditing: true, // editing will use mobile resources like cpu, ram, storage ( this will take time ) 
exif: true,
```

Comment: Thank you this was kind of exactly the same issue I was facing